# Replacing an item in queue if size limit is reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue

I want to create a queue with size 1. My aim is to get latest entry only, that is why I am looking for size 1 only.

**My implementation (problem):**

- `q = queue.LifoQueue(maxsize=1)`
- `thread1` calculates a value say `a`
- it inserts it in the queue `q`
- another thread reads the value by `q.get_nowait()`

I only want to get the latest value of `a`, so if new value is calculated by `thread1`, it should replace the queue item.

Is `q.clear()` a safe option here during `q.put()` put Or should I use something other than queue.

If `q` is full, and exception will be thrown, I am thinking of clearing the `q` in case exception is thrown and then try to put again.

Comment: When you say you have: `the queue q`, how did you instantiate the queue?

Comment: `q = queue.LifoQueue(maxsize=1)`

Comment: How about using ```collections.deque``` (which is also threadsafe) with a ```maxlen``` of 1? That way you'll always get the latest entry, because appending another entry (from either end) will remove the existing one.

Comment: Thanks, `deque` seems like a good option.